# How to write using hash map in this mongodb query using java

Tags: java, mongodb

How to write mongodb query using java in this

```
 db.Tasks.find({'assignedMember': {'$elemMatch': {'userId': '54782bfce4b086cb31d51dd5', 'status': 'ASSIGNED'}}}).pretty()
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Java code for the query in OP. You may need to change the collection name and database name accordingly in the below code.

**MongoDB Java Driver Version = 3.2.2**

```
import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

public class GetDataFromMongodbUsingElemMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();

        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("localhost");

        MongoCollection<Document> userCollection = database.getCollection("users");

        FindIterable<Document> users = userCollection.find(Filters.elemMatch("assignedMember",
                Filters.and(Filters.eq("userId", "54782bfce4b086cb31d51dd5"), Filters.eq("status", "ASSIGNED"))));

        for (Document user : users) {
            System.out.println(user.toJson());
        }

        client.close();

    }

}
```

**Test document used for testing this code:-**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583805ac204e6a612ebaf7e0"),
    "assignedMember" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "54782bfce4b086cb31d51dd5",
            "status" : "ASSIGNED"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:-**

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "583805ac204e6a612ebaf7e0" }, "assignedMember" : [{ "userId" : "54782bfce4b086cb31d51dd5", "status" : "ASSIGNED" }] }
```